# XlsxWriter chart without the Legend?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Hei!  I want to make a cleaner look on a train analyze project.

*Have this Excel speardsheet:*[image: Excel charts with explanation text box]

I want to show the chart without the **-Serie1** text box.

Some of the code in action:

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Year_sheet', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
workbook = writer.book
workbook = writer.book
worksheet1 = writer.sheets['Year_sheet']
chart_weight = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
chart_weight.add_series({'values': '=Year_sheet!$B$2:$B$13'})
chart_weight.set_x_axis({'name': 'Months'})
worksheet1.insert_chart('A16', chart_weight) 
chart_weight.set_title({'name': 'Gross tonnage'})
writer.save()
```

There will be severalcharts so it's essential to save horisontal space an get rid the -Serie1 text on all charts.  Hope you have some tips on how to solve this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#set_legend):

you should be able to remove the legend with this function :

```
chart.set_legend({'none': True})
```

or

```
chart.set_legend({'position': 'none'})
```

Comment: **Perfect** @titouanbou   _First suggestion worked just fine_